# EU privacy and data protection law for small WhatsApp group

Tags: european-union, data-protection, covid-19

We have created a small WhatsApp group to feed poor people and street children who are Covid affected in India. We are people from the EU, US, Australia and even from India. Members want transparency for donations. My question is, can contributions and names of EU donors be shown in the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the donors freely consent to such display, then obviously yes. If they do not consent there would need to be another lawful basis. It is not clear to me if "legitimate interest" would apply in such a case, and that is the only other basis that I can see as possible. It would probably be best if the group sought consent from donors, and simply listed "donation from undisclosed donor" for any donation from a donor who did not consent to disclosure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the assistance.